# for loop used to append a file in python but that didnt work

Tags: python

below is a code to append a file if a condition is met in for loop but this code doesnot print anything in the given text file. where is the error . the condition is met

```
with open("rollNameList.txt","a+") as file:
    for line  in file:
        if line in "george\n":
            file.write("george is tall and strong")
```

the text file consist of this name

```
george
ford 
black
reacher
tom
robert
chris
ben
mike
jasmine
```

Comment: You question is not clear, do you want to print text if george is in line or rewrite it to textfile?

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? Is the newline encoding the same between your input and your condition?

Comment: Why are you opening the file in append mode? The cursor will start at the end and the file will never be read. Use either `r+` or put `file.seek(0)` at the start

Comment: @mousetail, you got it! I missed the detail that OP was reading and writing to the same file, with the handle opened at the end because of the append mode. Good spotting.

Comment: top_hacker_mannn: this means that that your `for line in file:` loop will iterate zero times, you're never reading any of the contents of your file.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is opening the file in `a+`. When opening a file in "a" or "append" mode, you will automatically seek to the end. You can check it like this:

```py
with open("file.txt", "a+") as f:
    print(f.tell())
    # Prints 213
    print(repr(f.read())
    # will print ""
```

This will return a big number, the exact length of the file. There are 2 ways to fix this, using `seek` or using a different mode.

### Using Seek

First, using seek would look like this:

```py
with open("file.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.read())
    f.write("bla")
```

This will print the contents of the file. Other methods like readlines will also work.

### Using `r+` opening mode

The other way is using `r+` instead:

```py
with open("file.txt", "r+") as f:
    print(f.read())
    f.write("bla")
```

The `r+` mode is pretty much the same as `a+` except the cursor will start at the start of the file.

In any of these examples you can replace `f.read()` with `for line in f` or `f.readlines()` or any other file method.

### Writing to the file inside a loop

As @joanis pointed out in the comments it's impossible to use `seek` and `tell` while the readlines loop is running. So it would be best to store the lines you want to write in a list and write them to the file at the very end.

<del>Where you write in the file will also be effected by the cursor, you may want to `seek()` to the end of the file before writing and then `seek()` back afterwards</del>

Comment: I was testing something similar, and discovered that you cannot use `file.tell()` in the middle of a `for line in file` loop. Python says: `OSError: telling position disabled by next() call`. So contrary to my expectation, you cannot combine seek/tell with such looping. Instead, you have have to save the items to append in an array or some such, and print them after the loop.

Comment: @joanis :( that's a unfortunate design choice

Comment: I expect it's a consequence of underlying optimizations. `for line in file` is probably not reading just one line at a time, more likely a block at a time, so it's using the position for its own purposes.

Comment: Just tested: on my Windows machine, `f = open("myfile.txt", "r+"); l = next(f); f.write("some text")` prints `some text` starting exactly at byte 8192, which implies that the looping implementation is reading the file by blocks of 8192 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi since your question is not clear, I will try to my best to answer.

First I would suggest reading your text file and assign it to variable with below;

```
with open("rollNameList.txt","r") as file: 
    file_content = file.read()
```

Now you will have your content into a list like below;

```
["george","ford"]
```

Then with this simeple for loop you can check if "george" is in your file_content;

```
if "george" in file_content :
    print("george is tall and strong")
```

And if you want to change text to something else if "george" is present;

```
name_list = ["george", "ford"]


for i in range(0,len(name_list)) :
    if name_list[i] == "george":
        name_list[i] = "george is tall"
    else:
        pass

print(name_list)
```

At last you can write updated list into text file.

Comment: This won't work, calling `file.read()` on a file opened with the mode `a+` will always return a empty string.

Comment: Forgot to edit it when copying from question. You are write now edited.